# DNAC command accounting

Tags: cisco, tacacs, accounting

We are trying to integrate DNAC with ISE purely for Tacacs. We are able to authenticate and authorize users fine via Tacacs but we are not getting any tacacs command accounting sent to ISE.

Intention is to capture activity users perform on DNAC Gui.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure it does any tacacs *authorization*, just *authentication*. Doesn't DNAC have its own audit logs?

Comment: Authorization works as you can define custom attributes to pass on rbac information.

Comment: To update we have Cisco TAC advise that DNAC doesnt use tacacs accounting feature as its using API and would need to export audit logs to a syslog server